# how to implement progress bar in ag-grid table

Tags: angularjs, progress-bar, ag-grid

I have to implement progress bar in ag-grid table column ,  i have search in ag-grid documentation section but there is nothing. any other website for the same.
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cellRenderer config of a column to specify which function or compnent should be rendered in the cell.

Here is a link to examples that does not really talk about rendering the progressbar but it shows quite a few examples to render custom elements in the cell. You can modify the HTML of these to return and render an HTML div as per your requirement.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/

Answer (score 0):

Do like this may be it will help you (it is JavaScript version). to get more info click on below link . may be it will help you

https://docs.google.com/document/d/10K54wwj12IH9P1CI1Uv2k3MD__P8-LQDYqL8ofe9Exk/edit?usp=sharing

process bar is from **https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/progress/**

```
   const columnDefs = [
   {
       headerName: "Process Bar",
       minWidth: 150,
       field: "process_bar",
       sortable: true,
       valueFormatter: function (params) {

        if (params.value !== undefined) {
           if(params.value==""){
              return '<div class="progress">
                         <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="'+params.value+'" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">25%
                          </div>
                       </div>';
           }else{
              return params.value;
           }
        }
     }
  }

];

 const gridOptions = {
    defaultColDef: {
        flex: 1,
        resizable: true,
    },
    getRowStyle: params => {

      if (params.data != undefined){
         if (params.data.rowColor=="blue") {
                    return { background: '#f9f9f9' };
           }else{
              return { background: 'white' };
           }
        }
     },
     components: {
        loadingRenderer: function (params) {
           if (params.value !== undefined) {
              return params.value;
           } else {
              return '<img src="loading.gif">';
           }
        },
     },
     singleClickEdit: true,
     rowBuffer: 0,
     rowSelection: 'multiple',
     caseSensitive: false,
     rowModelType: 'infinite',
     columnDefs: columnDefs,
     pagination: false,
     paginationPageSize:100,
     cacheOverflowSize: 2,
     maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests: 1,
     infiniteInitialRowCount: 1000,
     maxBlocksInCache: 10,
     overlayNoRowsTemplate:'<span style="padding: 10px; border: 2px solid #444; background: lightgoldenrodyellow;">No Data Found!</span>',
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 :

- Use [Ag-Grid cell rendering](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-rendering/) technique and combine it with bootstrap or equivalent library to generate CSS based progress-bar

Option 2 :

- If you have AG-Grid enterprise license, [AG-Grid sparklines](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/sparklines-overview/) are a good option for this usecase.

[image: AG-Grid]

Answer (score -2):

One possible way: create your own loading overlay for the grid.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-overlays/

or

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-overlay-component/

In the overlay, you can use any progress bar of choice (e.g. Bootstrap).

Comment: @prarik wants to add a progress bar inside a cell in the table, not over all on the table.